# Save each row to file with unique index and map values to index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

```
Food:      Shoppers:                           Index:
Banana     Customer A                               1
Grape      Customer B                               2
Apple      Customer B                               3
Vanilla    ['Customer D', 'Customer A']             4
Berries    Customer C                               5
Lemon      ['Customer F','Customer A','Customer B'] 6
Nuts       Customer C                               7
```

I would like to add each index to a file that contains each row from the 'Food' column so each file looks like this: "1, Banana", "2,Grape" etc.

This is how I save my files:

```
i = 0
for row in new_dataframe.values:
    file_title = '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xx/xxx/xxxx/shopping/document{}.txt'.format(i)
    row.tofile(file_title, sep=",", format="%s")
    i += 1
```

Afterwards I want to use the same index to count if a shopper had an item on their list, that I can save to another file. The important part is that the index stays the same so that I can map it back later.

The file should look something like this:

```
  Customer A, 1, 4, 6
  Customer B, 2, 3, 6
  Customer C, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need flatten your list column then `groupby`

```
df.set_index('Index').Shoppers.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().groupby(0)['Index'].agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.astype(str)))
Out[300]: 
0
CustomerA    1,4,6
CustomerB    2,3,6
CustomerC      5,7
CustomerD        4
CustomerF        6
Name: Index, dtype: object
```